# How can I unit test the log file?

Tags: python, logging, pytest

I must run the script below by hand `$ python -m mylog` in order to test logging.

Why does `$ pytest -s` fail creating the logfile?

```py
#mylog.py
import logging
def foobar(logfile):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile, level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
    logging.info('So should this')
    logging.warning('And this, too')
    logging.error('And non-ASCII stuff, too, like Øresund and Malmö')
```

```py
#test_mylog.py
from . import mylog
from pathlib import Path
def test_mylog():
    logfile='./mylog.log'
    mylog.foobar(logfile)
    assert Path(logfile).exists()
```

```
>>> AssertionError: assert False
```

Comment: pytest will run function that start with ``test_`` as far as I know, do you put it inside a function?

Comment: @parsariyahi yes

Comment: well you import the foo but the code didn't run in any place, just put your foo in file like ``test_foo.py`` and write your code in an function like ``test_create_log_file()``, in this way pytest will run your tests

Comment: @parsariyahi completely rewrote my question

Comment: Pytest intercepts logging by default. See https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/logging.html .

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, I read that documentation before posting my question

Answer (score 0):

`pytest` has an built-in `logging` plugin, and registers `handlers` to it, that's why your `logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile, level=logging.DEBUG)` won't work.

`logging.basicConfig()` only has an effect if no logging configuration was done before invoking it but `pytest` has configured `logging`.

so if you want to have your custom logging you should disabled built-in `pytest`'s `logging` config.

you can do this by several ways but one simple way is to do is when you call `pytest` in your terminal:

```bash
pytest -p no:logging
```